# Color termcaps Konsole?

Tags: colors, terminal, ansi-escape, termcap

I've got a problem with ANSI escape codes in my terminal on OpenSuse 13.2.
My Makefile use to display pretty colors on OSX at work but at home when I use it I get the litteral termcaps such as \033[1;30m ... \033[0m

I know close to nothing about termcaps, I just found these escape characters that seemed to be working fine ! The strangest is that both my OSX and Linux terminal are configured with TERM=xterm-256color so I really don't know where to look for the correct setting I'm currently missing on Linux.

**TL;DR:** How to get escape codes such as \033[1;30m working in Konsole with xterm-256color ?

Edit: Here's a snippet of the Makefile I am talking about:
\Here's a snippet of the Makefile I am talking about:

```
# Display settings
RED_L = \033[1;31m
GREEN_L = \033[1;32m
GREEN = \033[0;32m
BLUE = \033[0;34m
RED = \033[0;31m

all: $(OBJ_DIR) $(NAME)

$(OBJ_DIR):
        @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
        @echo "$(BLUE)Linking binary $(RED)$(NAME)$(BLUE).\n"
        @$(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LFLAGS)
        @echo "\t✻ $(GRAY)$(CC) -o $(RED)$(NAME)$(GRAY) object files:$(GREEN) OK! √\n$(NC)
```

Comment: Getting *literal* codes such as you mention is probably due to differences in the shell (or make-program).  But your question does not show an example which someone can test.

Answer (score 0):

The example which you gave does not rely upon the setting of `TERM` (unless it is going someplace other than the terminal, e.g., via some program which interprets it such as the ls program, which has its own notion about [colors](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-output-formatting.html#General-output-formatting)).  It would help if you quoted the section of the makefile which uses the escape sequences.  Without that, we can offer only generic advice, e.g,. by assuming you have an `echo` command in the makefile.

The place to start looking is at the *shell* which your makefile uses.  One would expect *bash* to be the default shell on OpenSUSE.  But suppose you are actually using some other shell which happens to not recognize the syntax you are using, and trying to do something like

```
echo '\033[1;34mhello\033[m'
```

To help ensure that you are using the expected shell, you can put an assignment in your makefile, e.g.,

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
```

This assumes that `/bin/sh` itself is going to work as intended.  However, that is commonly a symbolic link (for Linux) to the *real* shell.  If so, one possible solution would be to change the real shell using OpenSUSE's [update-alternatives](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Packaging_Multiple_Version_guidelines) feature to change the shell to bash (or zsh).

For additional information, see the discussion of `SHELL` in the [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Choosing-the-Shell).

Reflecting comments on the version of make -- GNU make 4.0 is known to have incompatible changes versus 3.81, as noted in the thread *[GNU Make 4.0 released](http://lwn.net/Articles/569832/)* on LWN.net.  In particular, there are several comments relating to your problem, starting [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/569909/).

However, checking a recent Fedora, it seems that the problem really is that the default behavior for `echo` has changed.  As noted in other discussions (such as [Why doesn't echo support “\e” (escape) when using the -e argument in MacOSX](https://superuser.com/questions/33914/why-doesnt-echo-support-e-escape-when-using-the-e-argument-in-macosx)), this was done to improve POSIX compatibility.  You can get your colors back by adding a `-e` option to the `echo` commands.

Comment: Strangely it's not working with `SHELL = /bin/sh` but I get some of the colors with `SHELL = /bin/zsh`
Any clue where to find the correct setting ? Looked up zshrc and didn't find anything interesting, I'm currently looking through bash configuration file to avoid me having this SHELL variable set everytime I want a colored Makefile

Comment: I think the solution is outside bash.  What shell *is* `/bin/sh` ?

Comment: Ah yes I was thinking about bash instead of sh (though it doesn't work with /bin/bash nor /bin/sh) my bad, I'm not quite sure to understand what you mean by what shell is /bin/sh, isn't it.. sh ?

Comment: You can see (partly) by doing `ls -l /bin/sh` and seeing what the symbolic link points to.

Comment: For what it's worth, your example works for me with bash 4.1.5 and make 3.81, as well as zsh 4.3.10 and dash 0.5.5.1

Comment: sh points to bash, I have make 4.0 and bash 4.2 and it's not working :/

Comment: whenever possible, try to use tput to use color, it pretty much guarentees you will not get odd characters if the terminal does not support it, and as a bonus you can also use all those other features too, I usually put my codes into variables (short-lived of course):

Comment: RED="$(tput setaf 1)"  RESET="$(tput sgr0)"  and you can use the 256 color palette without having to do 38;5;x:   BGDARKGREY="$(tput setab 238)". You can also use tput to check if the code was supported, it will return 1 if not, silently (as long as it's a bona fide code, ie: tput setaf = silent error, tput fairy = error message)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution:

the problem was I used `echo` instead of `echo -e` which seems to be the default behaivour on Mac OSX.

Thanks for your help though, it lead me to good lectures :)