# Bash printing color codes literally and not in actual color

Tags: bash, terminal, iterm, ansi-escape

For some reason my shell script stopped printing my menu in color and is actually printing the literal color code instead. Did I somehow escape the color coding?

**Script**

```
#!/bin/bash 

function showEnvironments {
echo -e "\e[38;5;81m"
echo -e "      SELECT ENVIRONMENT       "
echo -e "[1] - QA"
echo -e "[2] - PROD"
echo -e "\e[0m"
}

showEnvironments
```

**Output**

> \e[38;5;81m
>
> SELECT ENVIRONMENT
>
> [1] - Staging
>
> [2] - QA
>
> \e[0m

I am using iTerm on Mac OSX and the `TERM` environment variable is set to `xterm-256color`.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the terminal emulator that you're using and the contents of the `TERM` environment variable.

Comment: TERM=xterm-256color
TERM_PROGRAM=iTerm.app

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes. I've edited your question to include this important information. I don't use a Mac so I don't know how iTerm would need to be configured to interpret ANSI escape sequences correctly.

Comment: See [*Makefile* Adding colors doesn't work on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36021056/makefileadding-colors-doesnt-work-on-os-x/36021490)

Comment: fwiw I ended up just outputting to a file: `echo "$stuff" >> myscript.sh`

Comment: (I had opposite problem, needing to inspect raw text, without interpretation)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are several apparent bugs in the implementation of `echo -e` in `bash` 3.2.x, which is what ships with Mac OS X. The documentation claims that `\E` (not `\e`) represents ESC, but neither appears to work. You can use `printf` instead:

```
printf "\e[38;5;81mfoo\e[0m\n"
```

or use (as you discovered) `\033` to represent ESC.

Later versions of `bash` (definitely 4.3, possible earlier 4.x releases as well) fix this and allow either `\e` or `\E` to be used.

Comment: I wonder how this is handled with zsh?

Comment: Works fine in `zsh`, at least in 5.7.1. I don't know if there was ever a similar bug in older versions of `zsh` (I see no reason to think there would be just because `bash` had one.)

Comment: It's less of an issue in `zsh` (unless you are trying to use it as a POSIX shell, for example as `/bin/sh`), because you can write things like `print -P "%F{81}foo%f"` in a terminal-independent way.

Answer (score 10):

Two ways to do this:  reference colors directly or assign to variable to reference them easier later in the script.

```
cNone='\033[00m'
cRed='\033[01;31m'
cGreen='\033[01;32m'
cYellow='\033[01;33m'
cPurple='\033[01;35m'
cCyan='\033[01;36m'
cWhite='\033[01;37m'
cBold='\033[1m'
cUnderline='\033[4m'

echo -e "\033[01;31m"
echo -e "hello"
echo -e "\033[00m"

echo -e "${cGreen}"
echo -e "hello"
echo -e "${cNone}"
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out. It appears that the escape character I am using for the color code is not recognized in my terminal.

Based on http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting#colors1 valid escape codes are:

```
\e
\033
\x1B
```

When I changed my colors from **\e**[38;5;81m  to  **\033**[38;5;81m it started working as expected.

Thanks to everyone else for the suggestions and help!

Answer (score 1):

Two potential things to try:

- run `stty sane` to reset the terminal settings
- check the `$TERM` environment variable